# Condition to check the value of variable in C

Tags: c

This is just for some extra credit, ive got a simple c program to calculate square roots, initially the program would just run away endlessly calculating them so i wanted a condition to check the value of the variable and if it is smaller or equal to i+(9^32)  to loop round if not to print end.

Unfortunately i can't seem to get the if condition to work correctly

If any one has any suggestions would be great

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int m, i;
  if ( argc > 1) {
    m = atoi(argv[1]);
  } else {
    m = 1;
  }
for( i = 1; i <= i+1; i++)  {
    double param, result;
    param = i;
    result = sqrt (param);
    printf ("sqrt(%lf) = %lf\n", param, result );
    sleep(0.5);
  }
  if( i <= (i + pow(9,32))
  { return (0); }
  else {  printf("end");
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect `a <= a + X` to ever be false if X is positive?

Comment: `9^32` does not fint into a 32 bit number, not even 64

Comment: @Mat - not even that, but pow(9,32) is larger than what can be represented in a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: What does "the value of the variable" refer to in your question?

Comment: @slugonamission: He also wrote `i <= i+1` (in the `for` loop).

Comment: if you expect i<i+1 to ever break anytime  think again.

Comment: Oh yeah, I never even noticed that

Comment: The `i <= i+1` will break (one way or another) when `i`overflows.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck yeah, i just noticed it is signed. so yeah, it will break, at 0x7FFFFFFF on a four-byte integer machine. On a 64bit 8-byte integer ? the sun will go nova before that thing finishes, but you are correct. it will definitely finish.. sooner or later. =). For four-byte ints, i'm making popcorn and catching a show.

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition in the test in your `for` loop:

```
for( i = 1; i < INT_MAX; i++)  {
```

**Note 1:**

You should probably stop way earlier: few compilers have an `int` (or `double`) type that is big enough for 9^32. I've replaced it with the maximum `int` value.

**Note 2:**

The current condition `i <= i+1` will cause the code to loop until `i` overflows. The overflow will result in undefined behaviour, although in most implementations `i` will wrap to a negative value causing the loop to terminate.

Comment: Thanks UmNyobee, I've edited the upper limit to the highest `int` value.

Comment: For what value of the int i do you suppose the condition `i <= INT_MAX` will be false? That is, what int is greater than INT_MAX?

Comment: Thanks Eric, I removed the `=`.

Comment: Ok 9^32 was only chosen for the context im using it now

I guess the question would be how would i add an argument to to stop when i == x

Comment: @JamesKirkby: As you are getting m from the command line, I guess you want `for( i = 1; i <= m; i++)  {`

Answer (score -1):

You need to read up on floating point precision. Hint: the numbers `double` implement are not like "real" real numbers, as used in math. There are limits, and 9<sup>32</sup> is a very large number, it's not certain that you can add it to another `double` and maintain precision.

Comment: Floating-point precision and `double` are not relevant to the problem in this question. The problem is the controlling expression has the form `i <= i + x`. Mathematically, this is always true for non-negative x. In floating point, this is always true for non-negative x. Thus, floating point correctly models exact mathematical behavior in this question.

Comment: 9^32 wasnt important it was chosen in a certain context i just wanted to know how to place an argument to stop the script running when 

i == x

i put a power number in there because i wanted to learn how to use it